# Google Maps mouseover event

Tags: google-maps, mouseevent

I am trying to get the google.maps.event.addListener to work with mouseover I can get it to work for click, but when I change it to mouseover no luck

Here is a link to the code
http://jsfiddle.net/alabrahamson78/kj7h4L5c/

```
  var map;
  var layerl0;

  function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.54406827862351, -73.99465471093754),
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          query: {
              select: "col2",
              from: "1gVbSjc3mwdsBtaBgieFJ1T5mK_zBBXyYx8gQTFVi"
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 2,
          templateId: 4
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(layerl0, 'click', function (e) {
          document.getElementById('cards').src =
              'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=CARD&q=select+*+from+1gVbSjc3mwdsBtaBgieFJ1T5mK_zBBXyYx8gQTFVi+where+col0+%3D+' + e.row['Code'].value + '&tmplt=1&cpr=2';

          document.getElementById('card').src =
              'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=CARD&q=select+*+from+1gVbSjc3mwdsBtaBgieFJ1T5mK_zBBXyYx8gQTFVi+where+col0+%3D+' + e.row['Code'].value + '&tmplt=2&cpr=2';
      });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: There is no mouseover in your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

A [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer) does not support the mouseover event (the only event supported is "click").  You can implement a mouseover type functionality, but it is not natively supported.  See [fusiontips](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/reference.html) for an example.